# Not being able to access env variables in sub folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dotenv

I have my environment variables in a config folder like:
`./config/config.env`

I want to use an API key and a provider from my env variables on a different directory: `./utils/geocoder.js`

If I console.log `process.env.API_KEY` inside my `./index.js` it returns the correct value. But when I use `process.env.API_KEY` inside my `./utils/geocoder.js`  it returns undefined.

Here's my code in `index.js`

```
import express from "express";
import { config } from "dotenv";

const app = express();

// Body Parser
app.use(express.json());

// Load env vars
config({ path: "./config/config.env" });

// Connect to database
connectDB();


// Mount routers
app.use("/api/v1/resource", resource);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const server = app.listen(
   PORT,
   console.log(
    `Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} on port ${PORT}`
   )
 );
```

My `./utils/geocoder.js` file

```
import { default as NodeGeoCoder } from "node-geocoder";
import { config } from "dotenv";

// Even doing this, it doesn't work
config({ path: "../config/config.env" });

const options = {
   provider: process.env.GEOCODER_PROVIDER,
   httpAdapter: "https",
   apiKey: process.env.GEOCODER_API_KEY,
   formatter: null,
};

export const geocoder = NodeGeoCoder(options);

// It returns undefined
console.log(process.env.GEOCODER_API_KEY);
```

Just to confirm, I've restarted the server and my computer several times, and still I get undefined

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem. As one cannot tell what the problem is based on an image of the folder structure.

Comment: We need to see at least a little bit of code e.g. how is `checkout.js` connected to other files and how are you reading the `.env` file. Also: Does this problem apply only to `checkout.js` or all other files in the subdirectory?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason here is the order of importing config.

Try loading config with dotenv as soon as possible.
Maybe even in the first line.

```
import {config} from 'dotenv'
config()
// another imports and the rest of the code
```

Or simple

```
import 'dotenv/config'
```

Answer (score 1):

hope this will help someone else.
the problem was in the path, you must give the full path not the relative path like you did here: config({ path: "../config/config.env" });
To fix it, you can follow these steps:

1. create a file  dotenvPath.js in your root directory at the same level as your .env file and add:

```
import path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

const fileName = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const dotenvDirName = path.dirname(fileName);
const dotenvPath = path.join(dotenvDirName, "/.env");
export default dotenvPath
```

import dotenvPath and use it in your configuration wherever you want. for example in your code:

```
import { default as NodeGeoCoder } from "node-geocoder";
import { config } from "dotenv";
import dotenvPath from "path/to/dotenvPath.js" //change the path to yours and not forget extension .js since you are using es6 


config({ path: dotenvPath }); //give full path

const options = {
   provider: process.env.GEOCODER_PROVIDER,
   httpAdapter: "https",
   apiKey: process.env.GEOCODER_API_KEY,
   formatter: null,
};

export const geocoder = NodeGeoCoder(options);
```